# Sublime Regex Find In lines

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have very big log file. Looks like this:

```
xx.xx.xx site.com - [SomeDate] "GET somePath" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) someElseInfo ...
xx.xx.xx site.com - [SomeDate] "GET somePath" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 8.0) someElseInfo ...
xx.xx.xx site.com - [SomeDate] "GET somePath" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; MSIE  7.0 rv:11.0) someElseInfo ...
```

I need to check how many lines contain '/windows nt 5.1/i' and '/msie 8./i'
How to do it in sublime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=.*?windows nt 5\.1)(?=.*?msie 8\.).*$
```

Try this.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/15